# expression engine dynamic variable names: {slide_{index}_title}

Tags: expressionengine

I am using a simple looping plugin so that my template looks like this:

```
{exp:loop_plus start="1" end="4" increment="1"}
<h3>{slide_{index}_title}</h3>
{/exp:loop_plus}
```

However, I am ending up with the following output:

```
<h3>{slide_1_title}</h3>
<h3>{slide_2_title}</h3>
<h3>{slide_3_title}</h3>
<h3>{slide_4_title}</h3>
```

Is there any way I can have dynamic variable names like this?  I am not looking for alternative methods for building a slider, I simply would like to know if the dynamic variable names like this is possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that Loop Plus (http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/loop-plus) sets the `{index}` part, so the question is what is defining `{slide_1_title}`...?

Assuming you have an entry field or variable with this defined, what you have is correct, but if it's not working, it means there's a parsing order issue.

Let's assume the code you supplied is wrapped in a `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair, what happens is EE will try to parse the variable first, so will see: `{slide_{index}_title}` which doesn't exist. The `{exp:loop_plus}` add-on will then parse it, converting it to `{slide_1_title}` (but to late as channel:entries has already tried to parse it), which is what is finally output to the template.

So what you want to ensure is that EE parses `{exp:loop_plus}` before `{exp:channel:entries}`, do this using `parse="inward"` tag:

```
{exp:loop_plus start="1" end="4" increment="1" parse="inward"}
    <h3>{slide_{index}_title}</h3>
{/exp:loop_plus}
```

This is a global EE parameter that EE uses to control parse order - you won't find it documented under the specific add-on. By adding the parameter, it means this child tag will get parsed before it's parent.

Comment: Great answer. Yes, `{slide_1_title}` is a valid field name. +1 for a great explanation.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it is to declare a preload_replace variable in your template and use it in your custom field name.

So something like:

```
 {preload_replace:my_var_prefix="whatever"}
```

And then in your loop, you could then use:

```
 {slide_{my_var_prefix}_title}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was afraid of and doesn't quite work because you can't set `preload_replace` values dynamically.  I would need the preload variables to update on each iteration of a `for` loop, which is not possible.  I ended up upgrading to 2.6.1, and the multiple relationships is what I really needed.  Thanks for your answer.